# Distinct or Group By Based on Two Interchangeable Columns (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a list with the following items

[image]

What I would like to do is perform some kind of grouping or distinct using linq based purely on the team names. For the example provided only one record would be returned as its the same teams playing each other even though the names are stored in different variables in the record.

It doesn't matter which record is returned.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How is your information stored, or what have you loaded it into in c#

Comment: Ivan's answer will get you there. It being best if you did some type of alphabetical sort before loading your data from say a db table to a class to "normalize" it so then you can group by a composite key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is to group by a "normalized" composite key, where normalized means for instance the first key being the smaller of the two and the second being the bigger:

```
var result = input
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        K1 = string.Compare(x.Team1, x.Team2) < 0 ? x.Team1 : x.Team2,
        K2 = string.Compare(x.Team1, x.Team2) < 0 ? x.Team2 : x.Team1,
    })
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom comparer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fixtures = new List<Match> {
            new Match { Team1 = "Eagles", Team1Score = 2, Team2 = "Hawks", Team2Score = 4},
            new Match { Team1 = "Hawks", Team1Score = 1, Team2 = "Eagles", Team2Score = 2 },
        };

        var results = fixtures
            .GroupBy(x => x, new MatchComparer())
            .Select(x => new { x.Key.Team1, x.Key.Team2, Team1Total = x.Sum(s => s.Team1Score), Team2Total = x.Sum(s => s.Team2Score) });
    }
}

public class MatchComparer : IEqualityComparer<Match>
{
    public bool Equals(Match x, Match y)
    {
        return (x.Team1 == y.Team1 && x.Team2 == y.Team2) ||
            (x.Team1 == y.Team2 && x.Team2 == y.Team1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Match obj)
    {
        return obj.Team1.GetHashCode() + obj.Team2.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Match
{
    public string Team1 { get; set;}
    public int Team1Score { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
    public int Team2Score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would say this isn't what was asked for, being a user-defined method and not a LINQ statement.